# Bitbucket get_tags() is not working

Tags: python-2.7, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

```
from bitbucket.bitbucket import Bitbucket

# Access a private repository
bb = Bitbucket(USERNAME, PASSWORD, repo_name_or_slug="https://bitbucket.org/ABC")

success, result = bb.get_branches('https://bitbucket.org/ABC')

print(str(success) + ' ' + str(result))
```

**Response:**

False Service not found.

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like username or password is wrong. Use the username returned in `bb.get_user()` instead of email id.

Answer (score 0):

Repo name should not be url. it will be a string.